# How to Prevent duplicate values in DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, listbox

I have a DropDownList in which values are coming through different tables. I want to prevent the entry of values in the DropDownList if it already has the same. I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
if(!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(new ListItem(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
```

The above piece  of code I am executing in page load event but of no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to get `unique` values from different tables, which prevents this condition check.

Comment: what is the reason for down vote?

Comment: I haven't voted. I don't see any reason to `downvote`.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can apply for your Question.
After Binding complete your DropDownList use Just following method.

```
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Use Following Method like...

```
    RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList1);       


    void RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList ddl)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ddl.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    ddl.SelectedIndex = i;
    string str = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
    for (int counter = i + 1; counter < ddl.Items.Count; counter++)
    {
      ddl.SelectedIndex = counter;
      string compareStr = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
      if (str == compareStr)
      {
        ddl.Items.RemoveAt(counter);
        counter = counter - 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FindByValue** or **FindByText** to match selected value or selected item from  dropdownlist

```
if(!DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedValue))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }

if(!DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    }
```